# Normal default probability vs forward default probability/conditional default

Tags: risk-management, credit-risk, default-probability, bayes-theory, actuarial-science

is the diagram correct in calculating foward PD(conditional default) ? Or should the formula be

Probability of default = probability of survival x forward PD

Which of this is equal to marginal PD(unconditional) and which of this is equal to hazard rate?[image: t]